# What is the correct way to send large data over TCP network

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, visual-c++, tcp

I was reading this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/revision-3-compressed-block-send-2) and it was saying there could be an issue with deadlocks if you send too much data without receiving. Is it bad to send the whole file over in a single send call? If so then what is the correct way of doing it?

I have tried sending large files using single send calls and wait until i receive it on the other end also. Sometimes the connection hangs. Maybe it could be a deadlock or improper use?

Comment: Since you mention Windows, consider [`TransmitFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-transmitfile)

Comment: You can send large buffers, but check the return value of `send`.  You can for example `send` 100MB, but if the return value is < 100MB, you have to transmit what wasn't sent by adjusting your buffer pointer and size remaining.  There is also buffering in the network layers.  If a buffer is full (nobody is reading or not reading fast enough) a  blocking `send` will wait until room is available.

Comment: Does the recv set to wait for the entire file read the buffer in the network layer even if the whole file is not sent yet? Or do i have to call recv with 8kb or smaller size to read the buffer fast enough so it does not get clogged? @MarkTolonen

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol.  `send` sends bytes but could send less than requested, and `recv` receives bytes, but could receive less than requested.  Check the return values.  It is not a 1:1 send/recv.  The only guarantee is the bytes sent are received in the same order.  Buffer the data received until you have the whole "message".  *You* define the content of a complete message, such as "send a 4-byte little-endian file size, followed by the file bytes".  Read 4 bytes, then buffer receives until you have the file.

Comment: So if I call send x amount of bytes and then on the other end recv same amount, does the networking layer beneath splits it up into smaller chunks or do I have to make that myself?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: there are no problems doing large send with TCP itself, but there are problems in the specific example you cite.

As for TCP in general:
Using a large `sent` is not a problem. The network layer of your OS will take care of everything. All you need to do is make sure is that the data gets actually transmitted to the OS, i.e. check the result of `sent` and retry with everything not already covered by the previous `sent`. `sent` will just block your application if it currently cannot send (write buffer full).  **But this requires that the server will actually receive the data.** If not then the server side read buffer will fill up which causes the TCP window to decrease and ultimately the `send` to stop until the server is actually reading the previously sent data.

As for your specific linked example:
In your specific linked example there is an application protocol on top of TCP which changes the semantics. It is not plain TCP anymore where the client could send without receiving, but it actually requires the client to also receive data. To cite the relevant part:

> The server sends one byte for every 3 bytes received.

Thus, if you send a large amount of data, then the server will send a matching amount of data back - size being one third of what you have sent. This sender emitted data will be put in the read buffer of your socket. If you don't `recv` then this read buffer will get full. This will cause the client network stack to signal to the server a TCP window of 0 and the server will stop sending data.

If the TCP window is 0 then the server cannot send anymore data on this socket. This means that the server will be stuck in `send`. If the server cannot handle `recv` and `send` on the same socket in parallel, then the server will  be stuck in `send` and not call `recv` anymore - which fill fill up the server side read buffer and ultimately cause the TCP window for data from client to server to be 0 too.

**In this situation both client and server will be stuck in `send` since nobody is receiving the data sent by the other and thus the TCP window stays 0 in both directions - deadlock.**